# responsive datatable not working with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

The header and footer are rendered twice, and sorting is working but not pagination.

What I have tried:

1. Added latest jQuery version
2. Included the JS files in the last when all CSS is included already.
3. Made table responsive on document ready.
4. I have converted page to XHTML and checked for any open tags everything is ok there

My code is shown below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
    responsive: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/morris-data.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="dataTable_wrapper">
  <div id="dataTables-example_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="dataTables_length" id="dataTables-example_length">
          <label>Show
            <select name="dataTables-example_length" aria-controls="dataTables-example" class="form-control input-sm">
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="50">50</option>
              <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>entries</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="dataTables-example_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
          <label>Search:
            <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="dataTables-example">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="dataTables-example_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="dataTables_length" id="dataTables-example_length">
                <label>Show
                  <select name="dataTables-example_length" aria-controls="dataTables-example" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                  </select>entries</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div id="dataTables-example_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                <label>Search:
                  <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="dataTables-example">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" id="dataTables-example" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTables-example_info">
                <thead>
                  <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 0px;" aria-sort="ascending">Rendering engine</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 0px;">Browser</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 0px;">Platform(s)</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 0px;">Engine version</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 0px;">CSS grade</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                  <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Gecko</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">Camino 1.0</td>
                    <td>OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Gecko</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">Camino 1.5</td>
                    <td>OSX.3+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Gecko</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">Epiphany 2.20</td>
                    <td>Gnome</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Gecko</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">Firefox 1.0</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.7</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Gecko</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">Firefox 1.5</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Gecko</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">Firefox 2.0</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Gecko</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">Firefox 3.0</td>
                    <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.9</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="gradeX even" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Misc</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">Dillo 0.8</td>
                    <td>Embedded devices</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">X</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="gradeU odd" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Other browsers</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">All others</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">U</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
                    <td class="sorting_1">Trident</td>
                    <td class="sorting_1">AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
                    <td>Win XP</td>
                    <td class="center">6</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="dataTables_info" id="dataTables-example_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="dataTables-example_paginate">
                <ul class="pagination">
                  <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0" id="dataTables-example_previous"><a href="#">Previous</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="paginate_button active" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0"><a href="#">1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0" id="dataTables-example_next"><a href="#">Next</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="dataTables_info" id="dataTables-example_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="dataTables-example_paginate">
          <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0" id="dataTables-example_previous"><a href="#">Previous</a>
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button active" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0"><a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0"><a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0"><a href="#">3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0"><a href="#">4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0"><a href="#">5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0"><a href="#">6</a>
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0" id="dataTables-example_next"><a href="#">Next</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a screenshot. Also please show your code in `$(document).ready()` handler related to  the table, i.e. DataTable initialization code, etc. Also I don't see [Responsive plug-in](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) files included: `dataTables.responsive.css` and `dataTables.responsive.js`.

Comment: I would love to include a screenshot , but the stack overflow doesnt allow due to lack of reputation points and the code i post is appearing improperly, however i tried to remove the themes for jquery autocomplete for this page and the rendering was ok now , but  still  the pagination is not working

Comment: You've inserted rendered code as if it was copied from code inspector. This code is generated by DataTables. Please post original HTML that is in your HTML file.

Comment: How foolish of me , i am ashamed to have asked this question its was caused because i was lazy to open the file and coped the table tags from code inspector , never realised its may be dynamically generated code . thank you so much you saved me from inventing table again :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented responsive DataTable many times.  Just read document [Responsive DataTable](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive). I hope this will help you. You have to add 
    .table-responsive
class.